# impresspages 4.0.13 linking to outside websites

Tags: impresspages

On my website when using impresspages 4.0.13 when I click add link and type in, http://google.com, for example it turns it into http://glymm-mere.org/12thnight/\"http:/google.com\". Needless to say does not work, how do I fix this? I have tried reentering after the fact but it will only re correct to the bogus website link.

Comment: Can't reproduce. where do you put this link? Is it on text widget? Or it is a redirect URL in pages management or somewhere else?

Comment: When I edit the default text there is the chain links, I click on that it brings me to area that allows for select inside, display text, etc and I put it in the top box. Am I putting it in the wrong area and about to feel realllly dumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just update ImpressPages. Just made ImpressPages to work even if magic quotes are on.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also

just add this into .htacces file:

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Please turn off magic quotes on your server.